# Continue to get a 'asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError'

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

The example below is only with 1 element being added to the event loop, with the variable `asins`.

I am getting a `asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError` error when the `asins` parameter below is 180 elements or longer.

If I create a list with any of these 180 elements, I get a successful response, which tells me the issue below is not related to the API.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this??  thank you!

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
import sys
import pandas as pd

def create_params(asins_set):
    params = []
    for asin in asins_set:
        param = {
            'api_key': '...',
            'type': 'product',
            'amazon_domain': 'amazon.com',
            'asin': asin,
        }
        params.append(param)
    return params

if sys.version_info[0] == 3 and sys.version_info[1] >= 8 and sys.platform.startswith('win'):
    asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(asyncio.WindowsSelectorEventLoopPolicy())

# creates a list of tasks to add to the event loop at once
def get_tasks(session, params):
    tasks = []
    for param in params:
        tasks.append(session.get(
            'https://api.rainforestapi.com/request',
            params = param
        ))
    return tasks

results = []
async def get_suggested(params):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = get_tasks(session, params)
        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
        for response in responses:
            results.append(await response.json())
        return results

def get_asin_titles(asins_set):
    params = create_params(asins_set)
    r = asyncio.run(get_suggested(params))
    asins_and_titles = dict()
    for result in r:
        if result['request_info']['success'] == True:
            asin = result['request_parameters']['asin']
            title = result['product']['title']
            asins_and_titles[asin] = title
    return asins_and_titles

asins = ['b07wp7q5bf']

final = get_asin_titles(asins)
print(final)
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem could be in the high amount of simultaneous http connections. Here you try to run all 180 http requests at once

```
responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
```

So, you need to limit the number of simultaneous running http requests. You can do it with [asyncio.Semaphore](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html#asyncio.Semaphore)

> A semaphore manages an internal counter which is decremented by each acquire() call and incremented by each release() call. The counter can never go below zero; when acquire() finds that it is zero, it blocks, waiting until some task calls release().

So, your code will look like this

```
...
sem = asyncio.Semaphore(10)

async def perform_request(session, param)
    async with sem:
        return await session.get(
            'https://api.rainforestapi.com/request',
            params = param
        )

def get_tasks(session, params):
    tasks = []
    for param in params:
        tasks.append(perform_request(session, param))
    return tasks

...
```

Now, if you run `responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)`, only 10 concurrent http requests will be run at once.

You can play with number 10 to adjust your solution to API rates. If you use `sem = asyncio.Semaphore(1)` all requests will be performed sequentially one-by-one.

Maybe, it will be still too fast for this API. Then, you can add sleeps to reduce your RPS even more:

```
async def perform_request(session, param)
    async with sem:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        return await session.get(
            'https://api.rainforestapi.com/request',
            params = param
        )
```